# How do I format this time/date in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time, timestamp

When I make projects on my website, I've saved the time and date that I made them on in MySQL as '2012-02-27 12:32:36' format.

How can I get this to display as:

"February 27, 2012 12:32 p.m."?

I've looked at other date formatting on PHP and read on the PHP website, but all of the functions they provide don't seem to be for grabbing a date in the format that I've saved it in.

Comment: Use `date` or `strftime`. http://www.php.net/date - http://www.php.net/strftime Use `strtotime` convert a string to a timestamp.

Comment: What is the mysql column type?  Is it a DATETIME?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, convert the `MySQL DateTime` string you have into a `DateTime` object by using [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/datetime.createfromformat)

```
$mysqlDateTime = '2012-02-27 12:32:36';
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $mysqlDateTime);
```

Then, simply call [`DateTime->format()`](http://php.net/datetime.format) with the desired format string:

```
$formattedDate = $date->format('F j, Y g:i a');
```

---

You can also use the MySQL [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) date function (to extract a unix timestamp compatible with [`date()`](http://php.net/date)) or use [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime), however note that these methods do not support dates after January 19, 2038 on 32-bit systems due to overflow (the two methods do not support PHP's automatic number variables promotion).